# Unique ID to field InfoPath forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-data-connections

My client want to develop some InfoPath forms, in which some general fields will have Unique ID in back-end.

`i.e.` Zone or Region will have common name in the form but, somewhere in back-end each Zone or Region have a unique ID associate with it.

Any suggestion how can I achieve it in SharePoint online or On-premise.

Answer (score 0):

To piggy back off of your other question, if you set up your lists that store this data, you can have the title field show the Display name and have a second field in the list to store the unique ID.

When you bind this data connection to your drop down field in the form, you can have it display the display name but store the unique ID.